# Python - How to make this recursive?

Tags: python, recursion, nlp

Newish to Python and even newer to StackOverflow. Still trying to suss out the best way to ask questions and receive constructive feedback. If I'm doing something wrong or need to provide more info, please let me know.

```
my_words = []

for i in range (0, 26):
    def predict_more_words(first_word):
        bimodel = build_bigram_model()
        second_word = bimodel[first_word]
        top10words = collections.Counter(second_word).most_common(10)
        predicted_words = list(zip(*top10words))[0]
        prob_score = list(zip(*top10words))[1]
        x_pos = predicted_words
        my_words.append(x_pos[0])
        return(x_pos[0])

    predict_more_words("is")   

    print(my_words)
```

I have the above code that I am trying to call recursively, such that every time 
predict_more_words is called, it takes the word at x_pos[0] and feeds it into the function again until it hits a len of 26. I am storing these words/chars into a list that I will concat with another list I already generated. It does not accept x_pos[0] as an argument and giving me a nameError - not defined.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why make this function recursive? It seems you're just trying to call the function 10 times and each time pass in the previously predicted word.

Comment: I'm trying to use the words to generate a sentence based on the probability of the previous word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this function needs to be recursive since there isn't anything inherently recursive in nature in this problem.

You can simplify the function so that it just returns the most likely predicted word for any word it's given. Then just write a loop to call the function as many times as you need, passing the previously generated word into your prediction function on each step.

For example:

```py
def predict_next_word(word):
    bimodel = build_bigram_model()
    top10words = collections.Counter(bimodel[word]).most_common(10)
    predicted_words = list(zip(*top10words))[0]
    return predicted_words[0]


my_words = ["is"]

for i in range(26):
    previous_word = my_words[-1]
    my_words.append(predict_next_word(previous_word))
```